# Are there any reasons to ever scope LiveData to a fragment's lifecycle, rather than to the fragment's view's lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

If we scope `LiveData` to the lifecycle of a `fragment` by passing `this` to the `observe` method, the `fragment` doesn't get immediate updates if it is only detached from the activity, but not removed, because only the `view` is destroyed, not the `fragment` instance itself.

Instead, we can scope `LiveData` to the lifecycle of the `view` of the fragment, by calling `observe` in `onActivityCreated` and passing `getViewLifecycleOwner()` rather than `this`.

Is there any reason to not scope the `LiveData` to the `fragment`'s `view`?

Answer (score 1):

If your fragment does not have a UI then you will need to scope it with fragment's lifecycle. 
Many people/libraries used and still use headless(UI-Less) worker fragments to have lifecycle awareness to safely pass on asynchronously retrieved data (Network Call) to the UI. (Similar to what Loaders do)